# jquery display an alert after each 50 seconds, how to?

Tags: javascript, jquery

anybody knows an easy way to display an alert after each 50 seconds in jquery (infinite loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`setInterval()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp), like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
 alert('hi!');
}, 50000);
```

Note this is just JavaScript, no jQuery library needed.

I assume you have a purpose, not *actually* alerting? :) Please let that be the case!

Comment: :) no I just want to piss ppl off with alerts popping up all the time :D

Comment: I am sure thats one site I would disable javascript on instantly... or just exit.